# need to close drop down on clicking on elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html:

```
<div id="contentTitle">
  <span class="btnShare">
    <a href="#">Share</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Post to Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Email Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Copy Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var shnum = 0;
    $('#contentTitle .btnShare a').click(function(){
        if(shnum==0) {
            $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','block');
            shnum = 1;
        }
        else {
            $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','none');
            shnum = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

The above code to to show/hide drop down, when the Share anchor tag is clicked. I need to close the drop down, when the user click on else where too. The above code doesn't support "$("body").click" function. Please help.

Comment: Can you please put your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: @SumanBogati Why not do it yourself?

Comment: Its very difficult to do it without `$("body").click`. The best you can do is instead of using click to open or close your menu, use `onmouseover` to open or close the menu.

Comment: "The above code doesn't support "$("body").click". What does this even mean?

Comment: @Pietu1998, its always easy for reader to come up with exact problem, and we know about jquery version also.

Comment: if I use $("body").click, the above function doesn't work. So, I was looking for alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var shnum = 0;
    $('#contentTitle .btnShare a').click(function(){
        if(shnum==0) {
        $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','block');
        shnum = 1;
    }
        else {
            $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','none');
            shnum = 0;
        }
    });
    $('#contentTitle .btnShare a').blur(function(){
        $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','none');
        shnum = 0;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will do it:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if (!$('#contentTitle .btnShare a').is(e.target) && !$('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').is(e.target) && $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').has(e.target).length === 0){
        $('#contentTitle .btnShare ul').css('display','none');
        shnum = 0;
        }
});
```